# List relevant search data taken from multiple tables

Tags: sql

Having a bit of problem trying to Join some tables together to find certain groups of bookings.  Here are the tables I have created:

```
create table Hotel  (
HNo char(4),
Name varchar(20)   not null,
Address varchar(50),
Constraint PK_Hotel Primary Key (HNo))
)


create table Room  (
RNo char(4),
HNo char(4),
Type char(6) not null,
Price decimal (7,2),
Constraint PK_Room Primary Key (HNo, RNo),
Constraint FK_Room Foreign Key (HNo)
references Hotel (HNo)
)


create table Guest  (
GNo char(4),
Name varchar(20) not null,
Address varchar(50),
Constraint PK_Guest Primary Key (GNo)

)


create table Booking   (
HNo char(4),
GNo char(4),
DateFrom date,
DateTo date,
RNo char(4),
Constraint PK_Booking Primary Key (HNo, GNo, DateFrom),
Constraint FK_Booking Foreign Key (GNo)
references Guest (GNo),
Constraint FK_Booking_room Foreign Key (HNo, RNo)
references Room (HNo, RNo),
Constraint FK_Booking_hotel Foreign Key (HNo)
references Hotel (HNo)
)
```

What I need to do is list room numbers (RNo), hotel numbers (HNo) and prices of all room types with type 'family' in descending order of price within ascending order of hotel number.

I'm a bit confused on how to join the tables to do this and then sort the order of the queries. Any enlightenment would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT R.RNo, H.HNo, R.Price
FROM Room R
   INNER JOIN Hotel H ON R.HNo = H.HNo 
WHERE R.Type='family'
ORDER BY R.Price DESC, H.Name ASC
```

It joins the Room table to the Hotel table using an `INNER JOIN`, and then applies an `ORDER BY` on Room Price DESC and then Hotel Name ASC.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.HNO, a.Name,
        b.RNo, b.Type, b.Price
FROM    Hotel a
        INNER JOIN Room b
            ON a.HNo = b.HNo
WHERE   b.Type = 'family'
ORDER   BY b.Price DESC, a.HNo
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)